# Typescript gives error during runtime but not on compile time

Tags: typescript

I am trying to learn Typescript, and can't seem to find the issue with my code, i tried searching but couldn't find any relevant material related to my issue.
Here's my code:-

```
<code>
class Hello{
    lars: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.lars = name;
    }

    sayHello(){
        return `hello ${this.lars}`;
    }
}

let b = new Hello('Metallica');
</code>
```

i compile the code using the tsc test.ts, it compiles with no errors, but when i run it using node test.ts, it gives me following error:

```
<blockquote>

lars: string;
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
</blockquote>
```

The file runs when i user Node test.js, but don't get the expected output i.e "Hello Metallica", while node test.ts fails.

Here's the compiled code:-

```
var Hello = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Hello(name) {
        this.lars = name;
    }
    Hello.prototype.sayHello = function () {
        return "hello " + this.lars;
    };
    return Hello;
}());
var b = new Hello('Metallica');
```

Comment: Sounds like it is not compiled at all or, maybe, you're not running the compiled script.

Comment: I am using VS code, and i am sure its compiling properly, console.log('here); is showing up in the console when i run the test.js file, but error while running test.ts

Comment: Can you post your compiled code?

Comment: `var Hello = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Hello(name) {
        this.lars = name;
    }
    Hello.prototype.sayHello = function () {
        return "hello " + this.lars;
    };
    return Hello;
}());
var b = new Hello('Metallica');
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the typescript. You're not seeing the expected result because:

1. You can't run the typescript. Typescript should be compiled to javascript, which then can be run by for example node. You should run `node test.js`
2. There is no line which logs to the console. Try changing the last line to `console.log(new Hello('Metallica').sayHello());` for example.

Comment: Thanks,  totally missed that. Any reason why its gives the error unexpected token ':' ? Am i declaring the type incorrectly?

Comment: No, the declaration is correct. You will only see that error when trying to run the .ts file

Comment: i tried console.log( new Hello('Metallica) ), it returned and object "hello { lars: Metallica }, also i tried to change my method sayHello() to return console.log('here') but it returned nothing

Comment: My mistake, I edited the answer. It should've been `console.log(new Hello('Metallica').sayHello())`

Comment: Sorry my bad, got it to work, thank you, i was following the tutorial at typscriptlang,org, and had not called the method sayHello()